# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\arctan\,n }{n^{\frac65}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

[Reason behind question](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%20of%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity%20of%20tan%20inverse%20%28n%29%20%2F%20n%5E1.2)

These were my thoughts on how to prove it.

Since $\arctan\,n \gt \dfrac1n$ for $n\gt2$, we can say $\dfrac {\arctan\,n }{n^{\frac65}} \gt \dfrac 1{n^{\frac{11}5}}$

Now we use limit comparison test, and since bn converges, and we get a number as a result of our limit, $\dfrac {\arctan\,n }{n^{\frac65}}$. Does this converge?

Comment: "Now we use limit comparison test, and since bn converges, and we get a number as a result of our limit, arctan(n) / n^1.2, converges?" Are you sure about the logic of your conclusion?

Comment: could you please post a readable post ? To me n^1.2=2n.

Comment: The wolfram link shows the intended sum. And oh yes I let bn = 1/n^2.2, and an = arctan(n)/n^1.2, i just read my notes and it said we cant use limit comparison test is the limit of an/bn is 0. Ok it looks like im stuck, furthermore since the smaller term converges, I cant assume the larger one converges. It could still go to infinity, so what now @Karl?

Answer (score 4):

Comparison test: $\tan^{-1}(n)<\pi/2$ for all $n$, hence

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}(n)}{n^{1.2}} < \frac{\pi}{2}  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1.2}} $$

and the latter sum converges (the sum over $n^{-\alpha}$ converges for all $\alpha>1$).

Answer (score 1):

As $\arctan$ is bounded, we can compare $\sum_n\frac{\arctan n}{n^{1.2}}$ with $\sum_n\frac1{n^1.2}$, which converges because $1.2>1$.